# How can I resize a web browser to force screenshots at a specific resolution on Mac OS?

Tags: mac, firefox, browser-addons, resolution

I want to take screenshots in a web browser so that the resulting graphic (.png, .jpg) is a specific resolution, for example: 1024 x 768

Besides adjusting my monitor resolution, is there any way to do this with an application or plug-in/add-on specifically for Mac OS? There is a Firefox plug in called [Window Resizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1985), but it does **not** work with newer versions of Firefox.

Comment: As an aside: 1024x768 is NOT a common browser resolution. The *screen* might often have that size, but that implies that the browser is smaller.

Comment: Do you want to include the browser itself in your screen capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last program I used for this was [Gadwin Web Snapshot](http://www.gadwin.com/websnapshot/)

I do not recall all its features but I think it can achieve what is required here.

Other options would be:

- **[Screenshot - Webpage Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki)**, a Chrome extension that lets you take screenshots

  [image]
- **Capture Me**, which is a flexible screen capture and recording utility for Mac OS X which features a floating capture window, several saving options, and resize ability.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra links ramon, I took liberty and added them to your answer

Answer (score 6):

The Firefox addon [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) supports resizing the browser window. There are a couple of default resolutions and you can easily add more.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the contents, not the browser window (and its toolbars) itself, then [Paparazzi](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/screenshots) might be quite useful. It not only has its own GUI, but also has a [URL syntax](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/urlformat) that supports invocation from any browser, including setting the size:

```
paparazzi:(maxwidth=1000,maxheight=700)http://www.google.com/
```

Turn this into a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) like so:

```
javascript:void(window.location.href='paparazzi:(maxwidth=1000,maxheight=700)'+window.location.href)
```

In Safari you can assign it to one of the first 9 places in the bookmarks folder, and hence automatically give it something like a Command-1 keyboard shortcut. Note that whatever browser you use, the actual screenshot will always be created using [WebKit](http://webkit.org/) (just like Safari and Chrome do, but different from Firefox's [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29)).

Paparazzi also supports some AppleScript. Or if you prefer the command line, using [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/):

```
python webkit2png -W 1000 -H 700 http://google.com/
```

If you also want to include the browser window itself, then I doubt there's a browser-specific tool for that, so you'd have to use your regular [screen capture program](https://superuser.com/questions/16613/how-to-take-screenshots-in-mac-os-x). To resize the browser window for that, I use the following bookmarklet (which, for some browsers might apply to the inner format, but for Safari and Firefox refers to the outer size):

```
javascript:void(window.resizeTo(1000,700))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want AppleScript.

Or a JavaScript bookmark now that I think about it.