# Getting higher resolution than Monitor supports

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, virtual-desktop, viewport

I have DG43NB mobo, that have onboard X4500 graphics. Its supports 1900 x 1200 Resolution. But my LCD monitor is only capable of resolution 1024 x 768. I have to test some websites in resolution 1900 x 1200, how can i test?

Is there any concept of virtual desktop using which i can simulate resolution 1900 x 1200. 
I have windows xp installed.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This answer may help you if its for website previews:
[How can I take browser screenshots at a higher resolution than my browser supports?](https://superuser.com/questions/120266/how-can-i-take-browser-screenshots-at-a-higher-resolution-than-my-browser-support)

The answer, Courtsey of Snark:
You can do it with Firefox and 2 extensions: Web Developer and FireShot.

Once both extensions are installed, go to Tools - Web Developer - Resize - Edit Resize Dimensions... .

Add a new size, 4000 x 3000 (1900 x 1200 in your case). check "Resize the viewport" if you want only the page content to be 4000x3000 (1900 x 1200 in your case). If you don't check it, the complete window of Firefox (with toolbars, menu, ...) will be set to this dimension.

Answer (score 0):

This 'viewport' concept is supported by some graphics cards.
Here is a [ATI reference](http://www.planningcommunications.com/virtual_desktop.htm).