# Print screen in higher resolution

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have drawing in my program window and I would like to do print screen of it. But Drawing with enough resolution not fits in screen. How to do print screen with higher resolution?

Comment: "print screen" captures exactly what you see on the screen, at the actual resolution of the screen, there is no way around that. Why do you want to capture it with printscreen? Maybe you can export your drawing from your tool (what tool do you use?). worst case you need to capture it in multiple parts, then compose them in a picture editor.

Comment: In what program would you want to print screen this from maybe we could find you a better solution.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You probably may find inspiration from here? http://superuser.com/questions/203490/how-can-i-take-browser-screenshots-at-a-higher-resolution-than-my-browser-suppor